# React Native equivalent to mousedown

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, touchablehighlight

If I'm making a website, I can use a [`mousedown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/mousedown) event to trigger something when the mouse button is pressed (and not yet released).

In React Native, I've got a `TouchableHighlight` and can register an `onPress` callback, but this only triggers when I release my finger from the button.

Is there a way to trigger as soon as a finger touches a button, rather than only when the finger is released?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved shortly afterwards! The `onResponderStart` prop is what I needed. This isn't actually documented in the [gesture responder system docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system.html), but it seems  to work for me!

```
<View onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}
      onResponderStart={calledWhenTheTouchStarts}>

    <Text>Press Me!</Text>

</View>
```