# onMouseDown and onMouseUp in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-web

I had in reactjs

```js
render() {
  return (
    <div
      onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown}
      onMousUp={this.onMouseUp}
    >
    </div>
  )
}
```

For the purpose of running some code while the user was holding down the element.

How can I do the same thing in react-native? Simply turning `div` to `View` and keeping `onMouseDown` and `onMouseUp` doesn't do anything on either event, and this that I found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44984892/3310334

```js
<View onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}
      onResponderStart={calledWhenTheTouchStarts}>
    <Text>Press Me!</Text>
</View>
```

Looks like unintentional misusage of an API

Comment: Use [TouchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)s

Comment: You could use the `Pressable` API: https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable and the `onPressIn` and `onPressOut` props

Comment: @NickParsons I'm getting this error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

Comment: @minseong could you show the code that led to that error?

Comment: @NickParsons       <Pressable onPressIn={()=>{}} onPressOut={()=>{}}></Pressable>

Comment: @minseong The conents of your pressable component should hold the thing that you want to be pressable: `<Pressable onPressIn={()=>{}} onPressOut={()=>{}}><Text>Press Me!</Text></Pressable>` (which you may be doing and just omitted for brevity). Also double-check how you are importing the `Pressable` component (and other components)

Comment: @NickParsons yeah omitted for brevity, this turned out to be the mrp despite being so simple. It needed the attributes before failing though. importing like `import { View, StyleSheet, Pressable }   from 'react-native'`

Answer (score 1):

You’ll want to use a `Pressable` element instead of `View` with a combination of `onPressIn` and `onPressOut` events. See more [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable#how-it-works)

Comment: Then I get this error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: `<Pressable onPressIn={()=>{}} onPressOut={()=>{}}></Pressable>` is enough to cause it

Comment: `Pressable` requires a child element. Do you still have this problem if you add a `Text` element as per the linked docs in my answer?

Comment: Yes the problem still exists

Comment: did you import Pressable from react-native?  does your react native version support Pressable?